# Plupload Show succes but images not in upload dir

Tags: php, javascript, plupload

I am building an image upload function for my website and rather than waste time rolling my own uploader i decided to use pluploader. I have used this uploader before and it worked right out of the box, but this time i can't get the thing to work.
My upload page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#uploader").plupload({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    url : '/plupload/examples/upload.php',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'

});
    // Client side form validation
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

    // Files in queue upload them first
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
        // When all files are uploaded submit form
        uploader.bind('StateChanged', function() {
            if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                $('form')[0].submit();
            }
        });

        uploader.start();
    } else
        alert('You must at least upload one file.');

    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

And then my upload file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Settings
//$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
$targetDir = 'imgs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads';

$cleanupTargetDir = false; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
} else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');


// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        fclose($in);
        fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}


// Return JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');

?>
```

I have all of these in my head:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load plupload and all it's runtimes and finally the UI widget -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plupload/js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.gears.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.flash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.browserplus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.html4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.html5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>
```

It works, as in I see the fancy upload box and can select file, hit upload then run through the percentage and then say uploaded. But then I got to my upload dir and there is nothing there. I have tried multiple locations for uploading the pics to and none of them work. And I have searched my whole host directory for the images and they have not been uploaded.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have got it to upload to the temp directory, but the second I replace the temp directory with something else it starts sending error code 100 Failed to open temp directory. Still stumped as to what to do.

Comment: can you specify what did u set in DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR variable...

Comment: I didn't, it is a predefined php variable. And anyway the error occurs even with a regular `/` used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plupload Show success does not means that you should finish what you want complete. That only means your pic upload to the server complete. After that, there will still be something exception happen, e.g. your dir can't make successfully or fwrite return wrong status.

You could use firebug or something else to debug the code, to see what is the response from the your server code, and you should make error_report on, then you could see the truth.

May that be helpful for you.

Comment: make error_report on? how do i do that.(i assume you mean js not php)

Comment: I ran it using firbug and i get this: `{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}`

Comment: @SpeedCrazy: Hi SpeedCrazy, that ret just means your dir not made successfully. I think maybe your account "www" can't write the web dir.

Comment: I fixed it, i don't know how, i just did something different and it worked. Thanks for telling me what that meant.

Comment: @SpeedCrazy: nice! BTW, the result "{"jsonrpc...}" you use firebug or something to see is the return result of your server, and the result comes from your code' output. the "{"jsonrpc...}" comes from your `die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');`. that means `$cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))` is false. this is the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the PLUpload widget's progress bar simply means that it is *sending* the file to the server successfully. It doesn't mean your upload server is handling the received data correctly!

It might be to do with PHP server settings as per my post at http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1985